# Is it possible to conditionally set the Enrichers in serilog appsettings,json configuration according to the level of the log entry

Tags: serilog

I'm wondering is it is possible in a Serilog configuration (done via an appsettings.json file to conditionally set whether or not to include some enrichers dep[ending on the log level.

In essence I'd like Log.Error and Log.Fatal messages to provide all the additional info but the others could just be basic information.